# Strange character before pound symbol in Titanium Studio

Tags: character-encoding, titanium, titanium-mobile

In Titanium Studio, I am storing a one character value in an SQLite database (which uses UTF-8 encoding). When I store a pound symbol (£), it stores fine, but when I read it back, I get ¬£ instead. Strangely enough, the string length still reports to be 1, in spite of two characters being visible. The main problem is that this character forms part of a filename that gets sent to a Windows Server. So, while in Titanium, despite the extra character, everything works, when the filename gets sent to Windows, we get another strange character. I tried converting the character using Ti.Buffer, but when I decode, I still get the same characters back.

```
var tipo_v='';
var buf = Ti.createBuffer({length:1024});
var l = Ti.Codec.encodeString({
  source: Vtipo_visita,
  dest: buf,
});
buf.length= l;
tipo_v = Ti.Codec.decodeString({
  source: buf,
  charset: Ti.Codec.CHARSET_ASCII
});
```

The variable Vtipo_visita has the ¬£ value. After the call to decodeString(), tipo_v has the value √Ç¬.

I also tried using CHATSET_ISO_LATIN_1, but it didn't make any difference.  How can I get this character to display correctly without the extra character in front.

As a final note, I found that simply doing

```
String.fromCharCode(163)
```

outputs the two characters in the Debugger, instead of just one. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: This is symptomatic of mismatched character encodings.  This is what happens when characters are decoding using different encodings than they were encoded.  What happens if you specify the same `charset` in the `encodeString` call?

Comment: I used CHARSET_ASCII for the call to encodeString, but the variable buf is now empty. If no value is specified, according to the docs, CHARSET_UTF8 is used.

Comment: In that case, what happens if you use CHARSET_UTF8 for both?  It appears that the character you are using is not encodable in standard ascii.

Comment: Using CHARSET_UTF8 for both has the same effect as using CHARSET_ASCII for both: the variable buf has zero length after decodeString(). In any case, I don't see why I would want to decode in the same encoding? What I need is to change Vtipo_visita's current encoding so the symbol will display correctly. I will try with CHARSET_UTF16 and report back.

Comment: You want the encoder and decoder to be the same because that means they're compatible.  If you use arbitrarily different encoders and decoders, they characters you encoded may or may not be the same ones that you get out of the decoder.  Or the decoder may choke.

Comment: UTF16 generates another different symbol. I think maybe I'll just make the program rename the file on the windows server and erase the extra symbol.

Comment: After reading up a bit on character encodings, I decided to fix the problem on the server side. This info is recieved on the server by a PHP script. I used the php function mb_convert_encoding to convert into ISO-8859-1, and now, the filename appears correctly.